# Google Plus Button not working properly

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to implement the login with Google+ in my signup activity of my application. I followed the google tutorial but when I click on the SignIn button it shows the dialog to select account and after selecting the account it do nothing. I think I've made some mistakes, 
here's the code:

```
public class SignupActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
GoogleApiClient google_api_client;
SignInButton signIn_btn;
private boolean is_signInBtn_clicked;
private boolean is_intent_inprogress;
private int request_code;
private static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 0;
private ConnectionResult connection_result;
GoogleApiAvailability google_api_availability;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor loginStateEditor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    buidNewGoogleApiClient();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    toolbar.setTitle("Sign Up");
    setActionBar(toolbar);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginStateEditor=sharedPref.edit();

    //Customize sign-in button.a red button may be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested
    custimizeSignBtn();
    setBtnClickListeners();

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetLocation.class);
                    loginStateEditor.putBoolean("success_login", true);
                    loginStateEditor.commit();
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Login attempt canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Login attempt failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

}
private void buidNewGoogleApiClient(){

    google_api_client =  new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
}
private void custimizeSignBtn(){

    signIn_btn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signIn_btn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signIn_btn.setScopes(new Scope[]{Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN});

}
private void setBtnClickListeners(){

    signIn_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_signup, container, false);

   LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
        request_code = requestCode;

        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            is_signInBtn_clicked = false;

        }

        is_intent_inprogress = false;

        if (!google_api_client.isConnecting()) {
            google_api_client.connect();
        }
    }

}
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //connect GoogleApiClient
    google_api_client.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //disconnect GoogleApiClient
    if (google_api_client.isConnected()) {
        google_api_client.disconnect();
    }
}
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (google_api_client.isConnected()) {
        google_api_client.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    is_signInBtn_clicked = false;

            Intent i=new Intent(SignupActivity.this,GetLocation.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    google_api_client.connect();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();
    if(id==R.id.sign_in_button)
    Toast.makeText(this, "start sign process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    gPlusSignIn();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        google_api_availability.getErrorDialog(this, connectionResult.getErrorCode(),request_code).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!is_intent_inprogress) {
        connection_result = connectionResult;

        if (is_signInBtn_clicked) {
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}
private void gPlusSignIn() {
    if (!google_api_client.isConnecting()) {
        is_signInBtn_clicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/*
  Method to resolve any signin errors
 */

private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (connection_result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            is_intent_inprogress = true;
            connection_result.startResolutionForResult(this, SIGN_IN_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            is_intent_inprogress = false;
            google_api_client.connect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please try from other account. I facing same issue.. Working with all other accounts but not working with my personal account.

Comment: i tried but it is not working for any other account too..

Comment: Pls read here https://github.com/ngocchung/googlesignindemo, use `GoogleSignInOptions`

Comment: Maybe you are testing with debug apk, and your key is for signed apk. Try testing with signed apk.